# Changing sprite animation depending on direction

Tags: 2d, android, physics, animation, sprites

I'm working on an android game where my sprite is controlled by a joystick. I just added an animation to my sprite with 4 rows and 3 columns:

[image]

Now I want to change the animation of my sprite depending on its direction. How do I calculate the direction of my sprite?

This is my controls:

```
public void update(MotionEvent event)
{
    // drag and drop
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        _dragging = true;
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        _dragging = false;
    }

    if (_dragging)
    {
        // get the pos
        _touchingPoint.x = (int) event.getX();
        _touchingPoint.y = (int) event.getY();
        // get the angle
        double angle = Math.atan2(_touchingPoint.y - inity,
                _touchingPoint.x - initx) / (Math.PI / 180);

        // move the beetle in proportion to how far
        // the joystick is dragged from its center
        _pointerPosition.y += Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180))
                * (_touchingPoint.y / 70);
        _pointerPosition.x += Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180))
                * (_touchingPoint.y / 70);
    }
}
```

And this is the drawing method in my sprite-class:

```
private void update()
{
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % BMP_COLUMNS;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
{
    update();
    int srcX = currentFrame * width;
    int srcY = 1 * height;
    Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `_pointerPosition` seems to be the position of the sprite you're animating.

If the player was moving the sprite with say, arrow keys, you'd need to compute the sprite's direction upon moving it, and get the angle out of it using `Math.atan2()`.

But here your lucky. You already have the sprite angle available in your controls update. Let's say you store it in a _spriteAngle variable:

```
        // (...)

        // get the angle
        double angle = Math.atan2(_touchingPoint.y - inity,
                _touchingPoint.x - initx) / (Math.PI / 180);

        // store it for animation
        _spriteAngle = angle;

        // (...)
```

Then you just pass it to your sprite drawing method, and choose your animation from it:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, double angle)
{
    update();

    int currentAnim = 0;

    // play "going up" animation if angle between 45° and 135°
    // (= in radians, PI/4 and 3PI/4)
    if ((angle > Math.PI * 0.25) && (angle <= Math.PI * 3.0 * 0.25))
    {
        animIndex = 3; // up
    }
    // play "going left" animation if angle between 135° and 225°
    // (= in radians, 3PI/4 and 5PI/4)
    else if ((angle > Math.PI * 3.0 * 0.25) && (angle <= Math.PI * 5.0 * 0.25))
    {
        animIndex = 1; // left
    }
    // play "going down" animation if angle between 225° and 315°
    // (= in radians, 5PI/4 and 7PI/4)
    else if ((angle > Math.PI * 5.0 * 0.25) && (angle <= Math.PI * 7.0 * 0.25))
    {
        animIndex = 0; // down
    }
    // play "going right" animation otherwise
    else
    {
        animIndex = 2; // right
    }

    int srcX = currentFrame * width;
    int srcY = currentAnim * height;
    Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null);
}
```

Comment: will try this 2morrow, but it looks like it should work :) EDIT: I am using a singe bitmap for my animation, with 3 rows and 4 columns, so there is no bitmapRight, bitmapleft, bitmapFront etc. Should I just change the bitmap im using and do it that way instead, because I can do that, or is there a solution for my case aswell? Just asking cus I want to learn about this stuff.

Comment: I assumed those were different frames of one animation, so that you would have different animations stored in different bitmaps. Could you just post this bitmap in your question?

Comment: I cant since I dont have enough rep on this site =/
But its fine, Ill divide the animation into smaller parts :)

Comment: Well you don't have to actually, you could just tweak `srcX` or `srcY` depending on the animation to play, if your animation strips are stored vertically or horizontally, respectively.

Comment: Im trying a bunch of different stuff atm. srcX changes perfectly but its the "1" in "1 * height" I need to change to something, but havnt figured out what yet, might be in a bit over my head here.. Never worked with animations b4.    
I've used this tutorial alot for my animation:  http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame5.html . But since he does not use controls in his game I cant really use his calculations for this.

Comment: if u look at that link ull see what the animation I'm testing with looks like aswell.

Comment: Well, in this case you can just replace the `1` by a column/animation index. I've adapted my code above to show you one way of finding this animation index. The tutorial uses a shorter but more cryptic way of doing the same thing, this might help you to understand what's going on. You just have to divide the 360° in four quadrants and figure out in which one your current angle is.

Comment: Just got it to work pretty well, not perfect but can fix small things like that later. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well, if you're OK with that don't forget to mark my answer as accepted ;) Good luck with your game!

Comment: done and done, your way is smarter then the way I did it, (wanted to do it like yours but my angles are a bit weird, for some reason my angle dosnt go from 0-360, it goes from -180 to 180). Been sittin with it for hours now so might try it your way 2morrow since its better. just got to fix my angles.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to grab the angle

```
point start; // center of joystick 
point end;   // current touch position
double angle =  Math.atan2(start.Y - end.Y, end.X - start.X) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Then use something like this to draw with rotation

```
canvas.save(); // so we can restore after we rotate
canvas.rotate(angle);
canvas.drawBitmap(...);
canvas.restore();
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587644/sprite-rotation-in-android-using-canvas-drawbitmap-i-am-close-what-am-i-doing